# sidebar WITH SIDE MARGIN with pure CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's easy [to create a simple sidebar with pure CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/hLvmyfqj/1/):

```
#page-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}

#content {
    margin-right: 200px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 190px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the `#sidebar` (red) sticks to the window and leaves a huge gap to the `#content` (yellow) if the window becomes large:

[image]

How can we solve this, i.e. how can we make that gap be added to the *right* of the sidebar instead to the *left* when the window width growths? Here is [how we can solve this we JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/24nt4z72/):

```
#sidebar {
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```
function updateSidebar(sidebar) {
    sidebar.css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    sidebar.css('height', $(window).height() -
        sidebar[0].getBoundingClientRect().top);
}

updateSidebar($('#sidebar'));
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateSidebar($('#sidebar'))
});
```

**Is it possible to achieve the same wihthout JavaScript, i.e. with pure CSS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `calc()`.

In your example, since `#page-wrap` and `#sidebar` have fixed widths, you can make the sidebar stick to the right border of the page wrap by setting

```
left: calc(50% + 110px);
```

The `110px` is the result of `600px / 2 - 190px`.

**[ [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLvmyfqj/2/) ]**

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple explanation to that. A `position:Fixed` element needs to be positioned by XY axis from screen, and not from his relative parent. The element is positioned at zero pixel from right of the viewport.

The best solution is change to `absolute`, but maybe you don't want this behaviour.

Maybe you need to research about sticky positioned elements:

http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

Comment: I know how `position: fixed` works and I've already changed it to `absolute` as you might have seen from my second code snippet. But `position: sticky` is new to me, I will give it a read.

Comment: position: sticky is not compatible with all browser. http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: I share with you a link where are the polyfills. Polyfills helps you to compatibilize with old browsers. Good luck!